# Data truncated for column 'diameter' at row 1 on Mysql

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-datamapper

Getting an error while trying to insert data into Mysql Table using datamapper ( Codeigniter )

```
Data truncated for column 'diameter' at row 1
INSERT INTO `purchases` (`bills_id`, `products_id`, `quantity`, `diameter`, `lena`, `lenb`, `lenr`, `thicka`, `thickb`, `widtha`, `widthb`, `boxes`, `resulta`, `resultb`) VALUES (1, 28, '2', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '1', '', 2)
```

Here is the screenshot of the table

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to insert an empty string `''` into `double`.
You cannot store `string` in a `double` column. Make sure the date type is `double` or compatible (`int`, `float`)

Either insert a `0`

```
INSERT INTO `purchases` (`bills_id`, `products_id`, `quantity`, `diameter`, `lena`, `lenb`, `lenr`, `thicka`, `thickb`, `widtha`, `widthb`, `boxes`, `resulta`, `resultb`) VALUES (1, 28, '2', 0, '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '1', '', 2)
```

or

If there is no value, simply skip it in the query

```
INSERT INTO `purchases` (`bills_id`, `products_id`, `quantity`, `lena`, `lenb`, `lenr`, `thicka`, `thickb`, `widtha`, `widthb`, `boxes`, `resulta`, `resultb`) VALUES (1, 28, '2', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '1', '', 2)
```

Comment: Setted default as 0 , but no change in error response

Comment: Try inserting 0

Comment: while I have tried this in localhost it's fine.On the live server, it is throwing this error

Comment: Even if you're trying to insert `0` (without quotes)?

Comment: Yes and default value is null